# Filter according several column data

Tags: google-sheets

I need to filter only rows that contains values in all A,B,C cells. I know how to filter according one column, But how to write formula that looks to 3 conditions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter:

```
=filter(A:C,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)))
```

or query:

```
=query(A:C,"select A,B,C where A!='' and B!='' and C!=''")
```

Comment: I bit confused where I can type this filter. I do Data->Filter and got three columns with triangle where I can set filter. But which column I should use? And why 3 selections?

Comment: Copy the formula into a cell where you want the data to appear. E1 for example.